# Using curl over a normal tor installation, not tor-browser-bundle, on debian wheezy

Tags: relays, socks

I installed a tor relay on debian wheezy and it runs fine. Now I want to use curl and I used:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9150 http://www.torproject.org
```

But it couldn't connect to the host.

If I start the tor-browser-bundle it works.

How can I do it without the bundle?

Comment: On macOS: - `brew install tor` - `echo "SocksPort 9050" > /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc` - `brew services start tor`

Comment: The question is specifically about Debian? Also you don't need to define `SocksPort 9050`, if it's not defined it will default to that setting.

Comment: for the url here https://check.torproject.org/ gives feedback if successful so you can grep content for e.g. either "Sorry." or "Congratulations." in a script.

Answer (score 8):

The main problem seems the port you are using. According to your command you're using port `9150` which is used by Tor Browser Bundle. If the bundle is closed, this port is not open.

In the default configuration Tor uses port `9050` as `SocksPort`:

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 https://www.torproject.org/
```

or

```
curl -x socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050/ https://www.torproject.org/
```

Your `torrc` should contain the following line:

```
SocksPort 9050
```

This enables the port which Tor uses for SOCKS connections and what is used with the command above.

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace <i>--socks5</i> by <i>--socks5-hostname</i> (the proxy resolve the hostname). Or you can use the <i>torify</i> command.

Comment: Also on modern curl you can use `-x socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050/`

Answer (score 2):

> a tor relay

This may not be running as a Tor node you can connect on. If Tor is installed you should be able to run it on the command line with no other options:

```
tor
```

Then test with the `curl` command you have above:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9150 http://www.torproject.org
```

In the console window you ran `tor` in you should see information about the Tor circuit and connections. Leave it open for up to 2 minutes and see if it outputs a message about the timeout. If the message says "waiting for info" then the SOCKS5 ports are likely wrong.